# Dynamically change Next.js style type for element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am attempting to change the color of an element based off of the result from a function

```
  //Example function 
  if ("123".includes("5")) {
    color = "boldOrange"
  } else {
      let color = "boldGreen"
  }
```

In my CSS, I have two classes, boldGreen and boldOrange. This is the tag:

```
 <b className={styles.color}>(-3.44)</b>
```

How would I update the styling class based off of the function? I am using Next.js as my framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with this:

```
<b className={"123".includes("5") ? styles.boldOrange : styles.boldGreen}>
  (-3.44)
</b>
```